# How to stopPropagation TV remote button events

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

How can I use stopPropagation for any TV remote keys.
I want to avoid the long press in case of press and hold of the D-Pad keys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any solution, for this?

Comment: @PrasanthJaya I have to use android layer to handler this case. Either onKeyDown or dispatchKey events i have to mark the event is handled so that it will not go down to React native layer